# Why does my electric range lack fine temperature control?

Tags: electrical, stove, stove-top

We had a Stove at the cottage for which all of the range elements ran either hot hot or cold. This made it very difficult to cook pancakes etc! We bought a new stove for our house and moved the old one up to the cottage where it soon (immediately?) began to have the same problem.

Could this be a problem with the wiring somehow? Or could it be caused by freezing hard over the winter, or is it just a coincidence. We are considering buying a new stove but I'd like to be confident it is needed. I have no confidence in the work of the guy who previously owned the cottage so anything is possible. I am pretty sure it has a proper side by side double breaker.

It did not occur to me to take pictures or anything like that when I was there last, it is a 10 year old stove that used the standard large three (four?) prong plug. What do I need to know to go up there and try to figure it out?

The Range has the regular 4 knobs that are each supposed to control an element's temp from low to High, If I set one to medium I get almost no heat, then if I turn the knob higher i get pretty much full heat, then I set it back to medium and it stays on full. Parts of the element are glowing red.

I cant speak as to the quality of the power, noticeable brownouts are very rare. There are lots of trees near the lines and it is not unusual to get an outage after a storm.

Comment: The range itself has temperature controls, right? And it's just that they don't seem to be working?

Comment: Is the electrical service at the cottage stable and well regulated?

Comment: see response to comments in question.